# image processing technique called PRUNING

Tags: c, opencv

does anyone have any idea how to implement an image processing technique called PRUNING? any ideas, examples, etc.?
I'm working with OpenCV and C #, if anyone can help, I am grateful.

Comment: As it is this is not an adequate question for this site. Do you have a resource where it is explained? What have you tried and why did it fail?

Comment: It is adequate, but it looks like there is no interest so I won't get into details. Pruning is commonly referred to a Mathematical Morphology operation based on the Hit-or-Miss transform to remove parasitic points. OpenCV does not support Hit-or-Miss directly, but you could implement the equivalent of it for the task.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking to *remove unwanted spurs and artifacts* from images. Have you considered using **Morphology** based operations? You can consider thinning, hit-and-miss transform etc. [This](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/morops.htm) and [this](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/opening_closing_hats/opening_closing_hats.html) give a very basic explanation about morphology. Most morphology operations are implemented in OpenCV using [MorphologyEx](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=morphologyex#morphologyex).

Answer (score 1):

There is no special pruning function in **OpenCV** but one can use the `prune` function of **PlantCV** an adapted version for plants.

https://plantcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prune/